# File upload with Selenium Send Keys causes Mime Type Error for AngularJS file upload

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, file-upload

I am writing smoke and regression tests in Selenium (Java) for one of my company's software platforms, which has an AngularJS front end. I need to  perform a file upload as part of a much longer test, but I'm running into some problems.
The button to upload the file clicks on a hidden input, which launches the file explorer. These tests run in headless mode on bitbucket pipelines, so I need to work around this by using sendKeys on the hidden input element instead.

This is the relevant HTML

```
<!--Action Button-->
<span class="pull-right">
    <form name="23" ng-submit="progressCtrl.action()" disable-on-submit="1000" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <!-- ngIf: progressCtrl.enableAction() && !item.completed_at -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-progress ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="progressCtrl.enableAction() &amp;&amp; !item.completed_at">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i> 
            Complete
        </button>
        <!-- end ngIf: progressCtrl.enableAction() && !item.completed_at -->
                
        <!-- ngIf: progressCtrl.enableAction() && item.completed_at -->
        </form>
</span>

<!--Hidden Upload Input-->
<!-- ngIf: progressCtrl.enableUpload -->
<input id="upload-postal-file" ng-if="progressCtrl.enableUpload" class="hidden-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" ngf-select="" ng-change="progressCtrl.uploadFile(file)" ng-model="file" accept="">
<!-- end ngIf: progressCtrl.enableUpload -->
```

This is what I'm doing currently

```
// Sample file to upload
File sampleFile = new File(Constants.TEST_DATA_FILE_PATH + "SamplePostalFile.txt");
String filePath = sampleFile.getAbsolutePath();

// Javascript executor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) DriverFactory.drivers.get();

// Find the hidden input element
WebElement input = new WebDriverWait(DriverFactory.drivers.get(), Duration.ofSeconds(DEFAULT_ELEMENT_WAIT))
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='upload-postal-file']")));

// Unhide the element so that it is interactable
String notVisibleClasses = input.getAttribute("class");
String visibleClasses = notVisibleClasses.replaceAll("hidden-input", "");
js.executeScript(String.format("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', '%s')", visibleClasses), input);

// Send the filePath to the input element
input.sendKeys(filePath);

_implicit_wait_as_a_last_resort(5);

// Click conirm on the confirmation popup
if(getWebElementAndScroll("//div[@class='modal-content']//i[contains(@class,'fa-check-circle')]/..")!=null) {
    WebElement confirmBtn = getWebElementAndScroll("//div[@class='modal-content']//i[contains(@class,'fa-check-circle')]/..", "Unable to find 'Confirm' button on upload postal file confirmation popup")._element;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", confirmBtn);
}

// Wait for the success message to come and go
getWebElementAndScroll(OPERATION_ALERT_MESSAGE, "Did not get success message");
waitForInvisibilityOfElementLocatedByXpath(OPERATION_ALERT_MESSAGE);
```

Upon clicking confirm on the generated popup, I get an error message "Call to a member function getMimeType() on a String". I think maybe the String for the file path is being uploaded as the contents of the file itself? Any help figuring this out would be much appreciated.

Apparently https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload is being used for the file uploads. The end result is supposed to be a POST request with the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` needs to have the attribute `type="file"` for the sendKeys method to work. Your test may need to add the attribute via JavaScript beforehand.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('type', 'file')", input);
```

(Untested code)

Comment: I have added this to the code but I am still receiving the error. I think the ng-model attribute is maybe playing the same role. I wonder if the normal send keys behavior gets overridden by angular in some way.